# Program crashes/stops after resuming from breakpoint

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I was trying to debug a Python program using PyCharm's debugger and each time I resumed execution after hitting a breakpoint my program exited with an obscure error (this particular program is based on Twisted and the error was about not being able to stop an already stopped reactor). The program ran fine within the debugger as long as I didn't stop it with a breakpoint, and it ran fine outside the debugger.

This problem started occurring sometime in the last weeks/month, but in the past I have been able to debug this same program without issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I just had a function call expression in the PyCharm debug pane that was getting evaluated whenever I hit a breakpoint and that function had a nasty side effect. It was left over from a debugging session several weeks ago related to a shutdown problem (so it kind of makes sense). I pulled a small amount of hair over this, and didn't find anything with google, before I noticed the problem. I hope someone else can learn from my mistake.